# Latest news articles in front page feed disappear sometimes

Tags: joomla-2.5, module

I have a minor problem with my site: sometimes when I navigate through my site, or away to others and back, the latest articles added to my site - displayed on my front page news feed - appears blank. On refresh all the news items re-appear. Whilst not being a major problem it may confuse visitors.

Uses "Latest News" Module which I think comes boxed with joomla 2.5.

Using what I think is the standard module in joomla 2.5 and with a template purchased from a professional site.

Any advice on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not normal behavior for the default "Latest News" module. From what you have mentioned, it would seem that you have another extension on your site using a script (most likely jQuery based) which is hiding the content of the module.

As you have no provided a link to your site, I can't help track the issue for you, so what I would recommend you do is:

1. Open you browser console and first check for any error just to be on the safe side. Also check the scripts in the `head` to see if any of them look like they're hiding your content.
2. Temporarily disable any modules you using on your homepage such as sliders or anything else that is animated.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I do indeed have another extension using jQuery. I would rather have both but have disabled it for now and will investigate further ,following your advice,at a later date.